# Deploy contract with Bytecode from smart contract

Tags: solidity, evm, assembly, create2

I have a contract that has a function `deployContract(bytes memory runtimeBytecode)` I want this function to be able to deploy the bytes sent to it as a new smart contract.
I understand that I will have to have the creation byte code inside that function adapts to the `runtimeBytecode` sent.
May be I could use some assembly with the create or create2 opcodes?
Any advice is welcome
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
function deploy(bytes memory _data) public returns (address pointer) {

    bytes memory code = abi.encodePacked(
        hex"63",
        uint32(_data.length),
        hex"80_60_0E_60_00_39_60_00_F3",
        _data
    );

    assembly { 
        pointer := create(0, add(code, 32), mload(code)) 
    }
    }


/*
  0x00    0x63         0x63XXXXXX  PUSH4 _data.length  size
  0x01    0x80         0x80        DUP1                size size
  0x02    0x60         0x600e      PUSH1 14            14 size size
  0x03    0x60         0x6000      PUSH1 00            0 14 size size
  0x04    0x39         0x39        CODECOPY            size
  0x05    0x60         0x6000      PUSH1 00            0 size
  0x06    0xf3         0xf3        RETURN
  <CODE>
*/
```

in this example _data is your runtime code

reference: https://github.com/0xsequence/sstore2/blob/master/contracts/utils/Bytecode.sol